# Почему не определяется длина объекта, полученного из хранилища Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Использую хранилище Vuex, чтобы отфильтровать новости по автору. Вот основные элементы:

```
Vue.use(Vuex)
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        news: null,
        author_id:'all',
        page_count:1
      },
    getters: {
      NEWS: state => {
        return state.news;
      },
      AUTHOR: state => {
        return state.author_id;
      }
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_NEWS: (state, payload) => {
            state.news = payload;
        },
        SET_AUTHOR: (state, payload) => {
            state.author_id = payload;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        GET_NEWS: async (context, author_id='all') => {
          let data = await axios.get('http://news/author_'+author_id).then(response => {return response.data});
                  context.commit('SET_NEWS', data);
        },
        GET_AUTHOR: async (context,author_id) => {
                  context.commit('SET_AUTHOR', author_id);
        }
    }
});
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    store,
    data: {
        selected_author: 'all'
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch('GET_NEWS','all');
    },
    methods:{
        async onGetNews () {
            await this.$store.dispatch('GET_NEWS',this.selected_author);
            console.log(this.$store.getters.NEWS.length);
        }
    }
});
```

При вызове метода onGetNews в консоли пишет: Error in render: "RangeError: Invalid array length", а длину массива выдает как undefined.
Если вызвать в onGetNews():

```
console.log(this.$store.getters.NEWS)
```

то выводит объект:

```
{__ob__: Observer}
12: (...)
13: (...)
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get 12: ƒ reactiveGetter()set 12: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get 13: ƒ reactiveGetter()set 13: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object
```

Почему не определяет длину этого объекта?Как определить?

Answer (score 0):

Вы уж определитесь, длину чего вы хотите получить. Длину объекта или длину массива?

Предполагаю что у вас все таки там живет объект, количество ключей у которого вы можете получить `Object.keys(yourObject).length`; вы же пытаетесь посмотреть свойство объекта length, которого конечно же не существует.

Comment: Почему не существует? При нажатии на многоточия в консоли раскрываются данные объекта

Comment: Не объекта не существует, а свойства объекта length . Length  это свойство массива, но не объекта. Как посчитать "длину" объекта я написал.

Comment: Не получается. Видимо обьект пустой. Что делать?

Comment: @ObehanProger если объект пустой, то длина его равна нулю. Ежели не получается, то возможно я ошибся с ответом. Может кто еще подскажет.

Comment: Ошибка, связанная с размером массива